# Why did Godzilla get wings?

Tags: godzilla-king-of-the-monsters

In Godzilla, King of Monsters, at the end of the movie when Godzilla gets his Thermonuclear form, and uses the Thermonuclear blast, he is seen to get wings.

[image]

This has also been added to a model of him:

[image]

Why did this happen? And is this something to do with the emission of the Thermonuclear energy, or some new ability (like flight)?

Comment: Presumably from Monthra when she gave up her energy to say him?

Comment: Yeah, the wings seem to be a side effect of the "fusion" with Mothra that occurred in that battle.

Comment: As @MrInfinity pointed out in that answer, it's not so much "Godzilla gets wings" as it is a symbolic representation of Mothra's power being used.

Answer (score 7):

Godzilla didn't get wings.  The wings were a superimposition of Mothra who had earlier sacrificed itself (converted itself to energy and merged with Godzilla).  It was a dramatic way of showing their combined power that looked good on screen.

Answer (score -3):

It's to make Godzilla seem scarier then it already is.

Similar to how Daleks in *Doctor Who* were thought to not be able to go upstairs for however long, so someone escaping from them has a place to be able to hide.

Some people think "I'll take a plane to escape Godzilla! If I'm high in the air it wont be able to kill me."

But if Godzilla has wings then it's that much scarier.